# I have problems with workon mkvirtualen, how can I proceed?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I installed `mkvirtualenv` with the command:

```
mkvirtualenv --no-site-packages geonode
```

But when i restarted my pc and used `workon geonode`, it's not working

> ERROR: Environment 'geonode' does not exist. Create it with
>   'mkvirtualenv geonode'.

Comment: @Rob The question is about Python virtual programming environment so it's perfectly on-topic. Like, for example, [tag:git] which is not a programming language but a tool.

Comment: To duebug start with `echo $WORKON_HOME` and `ls -lAF ${WORKON_HOME:-$HOME/.virtualenvs}`

Comment: I think this solved my problem